How I can clean my memory disk after attempt to clone the arcgispro-py3 environment?
I try to clone environment on conda(arcgispro-py3) but stopped it, because it took so much memory. So the environment on conda doesn't fully been created but the memory on my disk decrease. As I understand some packages clones and they took the memory. How I can delete them and return my memory on disk?
I try to delete the created folder in directory but it didn't change the situation.

what system do you use? What command did you use to clone, and to delete it? Did you remove all files in folder? Maybe there are hidden folders. Or maybe it moved it only to bin (trash) and you still have it on disk - and you have to remove files from bin. OR maybe you should use tool like CCleaner on Windows (or BleachBit on Linux) to remove temporary files, etc.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
